# Cypress cross domain cy.origin passing object doesn't work

Tags: cypress, cross-domain, automation-testing

I want to go cross domain from one website to another, cypress is letting me do this nicely with the cy.origin() function.

What I also want is to pass my page object model for the page I am on into this function.

I have tried a few ways of instantiating my class and passing as per the documentation into the args. I cannot get it to execute at runtime...

```js
const args = {
    testObject: new MyPageObject()
};

// As the domain has changed we need to use the cy.origin function
cy.origin(dfBaseURL, {
    args: {
        args
    }
}, ({
    args
}) => {

    args.testObject.getContinueButton().click({
        force: true
    });

})
```

Currently with...

[image]

Answer (score 6):

No, I tried this also, you can't do it.

The docs say

> Values passed into args **must** be serializable

Here is my proof of concept

```js
class MyPageObject {
  add() {
    return 1+2
  }
}

it('function serialization with cy.origin', () => {

  const testObject = new MyPageObject()
  
  console.log(typeof testObject.add)         // yields "function"
  console.log(JSON.stringify(testObject))    // yields "{}" - add() has been removed

  cy.origin('https://example.com', { args: { testObject } }, ({testObject}) => {

    console.log(testObject, testObject.add)  // yields "{}" and "undefined"

  })
})
```

Technically, you can pre-serialize the object and override the default serialization behavior for function properties (turn them into strings as you see in devtools), then use the dreaded "eval" within the `cy.origin()` to re-instantiate  all the methods.

But no, basically page objects are not a good fit with the Cypress paradigm.

---

**Using JSON or object instead**

As suggested in the notes, a simple object can be used to pass selectors in.

```js
const selectors = requires('selectors.json')

/* 
 Selectors is an object with string properties, it is serializable
 {
   login: 'input#user-name',
   ...
*/

it('object map of selectors with cy.origin', () => {
  
  console.log(typeof selectors.login)        // yields "string"
  console.log(JSON.stringify(selectors))     // yields "{login: ...}" 

  cy.origin('https://example.com', { args: {selectors} }, ({selectors}) => {

    console.log(JSON.stringify(selectors))   // yields "{login: ...}" 

  })
})
```

Comment: Can I pass a .json file through then with the selectors I want in there?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66122697/how-to-create-and-call-selectors-from-a-separate-file-in-cypress

Comment: You certainly can. Only functions (methods) are a problem, because of possible references to variables in the outer scope (closure variables).

Comment: Thanks, that worked. No page objects for a cy.origin call, just use a .json file full of your selectors.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably instantiate your class by replacing

```
testObject: new MyPageObject
```

by

```
testObject: new MyPageObject()
```

Comment: Good spot, let me try that.

Comment: I'm getting the same error...is it not possible? From Cypress documentation page.

Yielding a value
Values returned or yielded from the callback function must be serializable or they will not be returned to the primary origin.